# Spring batch step fault tolerance not working on unique constraint

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch to import csv data and save them as JPA entity in database.

Here is my writer:

```
@Bean
public ItemWriter<HotelChain> hotelChainWriter(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    JpaItemWriter<HotelChain> writer = new JpaItemWriter<>();
    writer.setEntityManagerFactory(factory);
    return writer;
}
```

job method:

```
@Bean
public Step hotelStep1(ItemWriter<Hotel> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("hotelStep1").<HotelCSVDto, Hotel>chunk(50).reader(hotelReader())
            .processor(hotelProcessor()).writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(ConflictException.class)
            .skip(ConstraintViolationException.class)
            .skip(PSQLException.class)
            .noRetry(ConflictException.class)
            .noRetry(ConstraintViolationException.class)
            .noRetry(PSQLException.class)
            .skipLimit(150)
            .build();
}
```

Error message:

```
2018-03-27 10:26:16.596 ERROR 7493 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hotel__public_id_idx"
  Detail: Key (public_id)=(HILTON_GARDEN_INN_TALLAHASSEE-US-FL-TALLAHASSEE) already exists.
2018-03-27 10:26:16.879 ERROR 7493 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step hotelStep1 in job importCityJob

org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt in recovery path, but exception is not skippable.; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:512) ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692) ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112) ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hotel__public_id_idx"
  Detail: Key (public_id)=(HILTON_GARDEN_INN_TALLAHASSEE-US-FL-TALLAHASSEE) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)...
```

I'd like to know why the `faultTolerance` does not work, and how should I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem!

Comment: I am facing the same problem too: a constraint violation exception is thrown but the step finished with status complete. The custom skip policy nor the skip listener is invoked